# Unable to install Ant.exe application

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I am trying to install ant.exe application in Ubuntu 20.04. The error message what i am getting is:

> Setup cannot continue until all the system components have been successfully installed.

Please help on this.

Comment: There is a dearth of information here. Could you edit your question to include details like which operating system and version you're running, how you're trying to install a Windows application on that system, and what sort of error messages you might have? Without some basic information there is no way anyone can accurately answer your question.

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: I am trying to install in ubuntu 20.04. The error message what i am getting is setup cannot continue until all the system components have been successfully installed.

Comment: What are you trying to install, and how? Include as much information as possible.